# How to compose Hystrix observables using java8 and rxjava

Tags: rx-java, hystrix

I got two api's to invoke. both them wrapped with Hystrix Observable:

here is one for example:

```
@HystrixCommand()
    public Observable<String> getAvailableFlightBookings() {
        return new ObservableResult<String>() {
            @Override
            public String invoke() {
                URI uri = registryService.getServiceUrl("flight-booking-service", "http://localhost:8081/flight-booking-service");
                String url = uri.toString() + "/flights/list";
                ResponseEntity<String> resultStr = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
                return resultStr.getBody();
            }
        };
    }
```

I have the following code which I am struggling to complete:

```
public DeferredResult<FlightDetails> getAllFlightDetails() {
        //Calling previous defined functions
        Observable<String> availableFlightBookings=flightBookingIntegrationService.getAvailableFlightBookings();
        Observable<String> couponId=couponIntegrationService.getCoupon();


        Observable<String> details = Observable.zip(

    ..?


    }
```

I am not sure how to invoke the following API's:

```
flightBookingIntegrationService.getAvailableFlightBookings();
couponIntegrationService.getCoupon();
```

and populate the final result object (FlightDetails) using the Observable.zip

FlightDetails:

```
public class FlightDetails {

    String couponId;
    String availableFlightList;

..
}
```

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your Hystrix command class a `@Component` since you are using Spring, then just `Autowire` it into yout controller and call

And using lambdas, will look something like this:

```
public DeferredResult<FlightDetails> getAllFlightDetails() {

    Observable<String> availableFlightBookings=flightBookingIntegrationService.getAvailableFlightBookings();
    Observable<String> couponId=couponIntegrationService.getCoupon();

    //Create a new DeferredResult
    DeferredResult<FlightDetails> result = new DeferredResult();

    Observable.zip(availableFlightBookings,couponId, (avaliable, coupon) -> {
     // do some logic here or just..
    return new FlightDetails(avaliable,coupon);
    }).subscribe(result::setResult,result::setErrorResult);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: BTW If you just want to create a new instance of `FlightDetails` you can use method reference instead of lambda

Comment: Can you please explain why using the DeferredResult?

Comment: And the meaning of using (avaliable, coupon) .

Comment: First, because you were already using, and also, this will trigger async processing by spring, so you don't need to block the Observable to get a result, Spring Cloud will bring the possibility to return Observable from a controller, then, you do not need the Deferred this will be done by the framework

Comment: The (available, coupon) is just the names of the parameters of the function you need to pass on a zip operaration, since we are using Java 8 lambdas we do not need to have a anonymous call, you can call the variables whatever you want to

Comment: Thanks for your response. but it didnt work out for me. Seems like the code never trigger the services and therfor a null is being returned. I uploaded the project into github please check this execution at: https://github.com/IdanFridman/BootNetflixExample/blob/master/core/flight-integration-service/src/main/java/com/bootnetflix/flight_integration_service/service/FlightIntegrationService.java#L67  let me know what do you think. thank you.

Comment: I am gettig this error: Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getCoupon failed and failed retrieving fallback.  but if I try to reach coupon service without javarx I managed

Comment: Using Observable, you need to return a ObservableResult on a method annotated with HystrixCommand, the failure can be another reason, like the service request returned a 404 or the fallback method is misspelled, shall we continue this on a issue on Github?

Comment: Yes. I am going to mark your answer as yes since you answerd it right. seems like when invoking this: https://github.com/IdanFridman/BootNetflixExample/blob/master/core/flight-integration-service/src/main/java/com/bootnetflix/flight_integration_service/service/FlightBookingIntegrationService.java#L33  I get the exception. If I just return String there without invoking that rest it's all working.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Hystrix, but zipping two observables shouldn't be different from pure RxJava.

```
Observable.zip(availableFlightBookings, couponId, new Func2<String, String, FlightDetails>() {
    @Override
    public FlightDetails call(String availableFlights, String coupon) {
        return new FlightDetails(availableFlights, coupon);
    }
}).subscribe();
```